# How do I use a Kotlin Deferred (Coroutine) object in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have some Java code which at some point needs to pause and wait for a result. I am trying to solve this problem using Kotlin Coroutines.

The async method of BuilderKt allows me to pass the work off to the background successfully. But I'm unclear on how to do a non-blocking wait for the result.

Here is how I setup the work (and get a Deferred):

```
Deferred<T> deferred = BuildersKt.async(GlobalScope.INSTANCE, Dispatchers.getIO(), CoroutineStart.DEFAULT, new Function2<CoroutineScope, Continuation<? super T>, T>() {
    @Override
    public T invoke(CoroutineScope coroutineScope, Continuation<? super T> continuation) {
        return /* Do some work and return a T */;
    }
});
```

The part I'm having trouble with is the await requires a continuation and returns nothing

```
deferred.await(new Continuation<T>() {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CoroutineContext getContext() {
        return ???;
    }

    @Override
    public void resumeWith(@NotNull Object o) {
        ???
    }

});
```

If I can't make it do a non-blocking await, I would need to keep polling to check if it's complete which is obviously not the right approach. **What pieces of this puzzle am I missing?**

The Kotlin documentation has no examples on how to use it with Java and there's no useful javadoc for the methods in the continuation

Comment: Kotlin coroutines are not intended to be used with Java, because they don't really buy you anything without being able to use `suspend` function syntax. I guess it's possible, but you would only do it if having to interact with a Kotlin suspend function from Java code. It would be easier to use Java's concurrent library.

Comment: Right, thanks, but do you know how to do it anyway? @Tenfour04

Comment: I've never attempted it. Pretty sure you can't just instantiate a continuation to pass to `await`. The continuation basically *is* the coroutine. There should be only one continuation produced from either a `launch` or `async` call. Try storing the `continuation` passed to your `async` callback and using that.

Comment: That's how it seems to me too, yet the async call produces a Deferred that I can't seem to use (or don't understand properly). In Kotlin code the await method has no params

Comment: Kotlin functions marked with `suspend` basically have a hidden `continuation` parameter that is passed around everywhere in Java. Try storing the `continuation` passed to your `async` callback and using that where it's called for.